# Plot line that lies in a 2D plane in 3D axes in R

Tags: r

I would like to make the following plot in R. It is just a normal density sitting upright.

[image: 2D line in 3D Axes]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the `scatterplot3d` package

```
library(scatterplot3d)

d <- rnorm(10000)
y <- density(d)$y
x <- density(d)$x
z <- rep(0, length(x))
scatterplot3d(x=x, y=z, z=y, type="l")
```

[image]